# Как получить подстроку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `/anyString/1d1cd0b2-ee38-4296-912c-43b16f84d1ba/`

Как получть только хэш `1d1cd0b2-ee38-4296-912c-43b16f84d1ba` из этой строки, без `/` слешей и `anyString`, при том, что anyString может быть любым словом?

Comment: Если это будет использоваться в каком либо языке программирования, то проверьте существует ли в нем split или его аналоги

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Да это можно сделать через регулярки (согласно тегу), но это будет пальба из пушки по воробьям.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант реализации на JavaScript...

```js
const str = '/anyString/1d1cd0b2-ee38-4296-912c-43b16f84d1ba/'
const re = /[^\/]+(?=\/$)/
console.log(str.match(re))
```